# What does approve button in suggested edits do?

Tags: support

I received an email today informing I have something in my inbox, when I clicked the link, it opened a page showing suggested edits to my closed question, on the page I'm shown on that users winny and JYelton have rejected the edits, to far right of this information is an Approve button.

What does this approve button do, does it approve those users' rejection of the edit or does it approve suggested edit.

Comment: It depends on if you are in the review que or if the edit is accepting an answer to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click approve on [this edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/253667), it will approve the suggested edit and override the decision of the two other reviewers. This is [relatively new functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/295232).

Note that there is a gray banner between the navigation bar and the Approve button (only visible for you). It states exactly what happens when you click 'Approve':

> This suggested edit to your post has already been handled and your action is no longer required.
>
> If you disagree with this edit being rejected, you can apply it to your post using the Approve button below.

---

But it looks like the user wanted to write an *answer* to your question, so they're completely changing the meaning of your post. They could probably better [ask and answer a question themselves](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), though I can't comment on the validity of what they're writing.

Comment: I must have missed that information. It is unclear if the user wanted to answer my question or proposed edits to my question to have reopened. The information in their post is helpful, although technology used is different. I asked if microwaves can be used to send audio messages and the user showed similar technology made using sound, specifically ultra sound at 65KHz.

Comment: @noviceFedora There are times when users will edit questions or answers to try and respond, rather than posting a comment or answer separately. Such edits are often flagged for review, and we try to determine whether the edit is improving/fixing something. In cases where "responses" are attempted, or wholly new information inserted, we usually reject it. In this case, a rep 1 user was trying to respond, but was doing so by erasing everything you wrote to post it.